# Trouble with enter/return key in keyboard handler

Tags: c#, user-interface, events, handler, calculator

I'm starting with C#, and I'm doing a calculator as my first project. I want a keyboard handler for my GUI that makes the same operations as the button handlers that I did before. The problem is when I get to the "enter" key. That's my void:

```
private void keyboardHandler(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
  char keyPressed = e.KeyChar;
  if (keyPressed >= (char)Keys.D0 && keyPressed <= (char)Keys.D9)
  {
    //Some stuff
  }
  else if (keyPressed == (char)Keys.Back)
  {
    //More stuff
  }
  else if (keyPressed == (char)Keys.Enter || keyPressed == (char)Keys.Return)
  {
    this.operate();
    operator = operation.START;
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I press the enter key, it throws the handler event BUT it also press the button as if I click on it. Here's an image:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `ProcessCmdKey` handler for your form.

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.operate();
            operator = operation.START;
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: *This method is called during message preprocessing to handle command keys. Command keys are keys that always take precedence over regular input keys*
more you can find here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` property to `true`.

So this tells the operating system, or normal window messaging func (WndProc) to ignore the key press as it's already been dealth with.  See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So like:

```
private void keyboardHandler(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
  char keyPressed = e.KeyChar;
  if (keyPressed >= (char)Keys.D0 && keyPressed <= (char)Keys.D9)
  {
    //Some stuff
  }
  else if (keyPressed == (char)Keys.Back)
  {
    //More stuff
  }
  else if (keyPressed == (char)Keys.Enter || keyPressed == (char)Keys.Return)
  {
    this.operate();
    operator = operation.START;
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't fix it, it's still the same :\

Comment: Are you handling the key press event on a text box, the form or where.  Your function doesn't indicate from where the event is emanating.

Comment: I'm handling it in the form, all the buttons and the textbox (you can see all in the image). Could that be the reason?

Comment: Can you add the designer code to the question?  So I can see where you're hooking up the event handlers?

Comment: this.xxx.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.manejadorTeclado); in all buttons and the textbox and 
this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.manejadorTeclado); for the form

Comment: Melya answer fixed it (i'd give you +1 anyway :P)

Comment: Thank you, glad you got your answer. :)